# _AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAudioEngine.mm:353:AttachNode: (node != nil)] while creating AKDelay

Tags: swift, macos, audiokit

I have a minimal MacOS app (one view controller + one button) with the following code (basically a copy-paste from [AudioKit's playground](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/Playgrounds/AudioKitPlaygrounds/Playgrounds/Synthesis.playground/Pages/Plucked%20String.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift)):

```
public class Player {

    static let playRate = 2.0
    static let scale = [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12]

    var pluckedString: AKPluckedString! = nil
    var delay: AKDelay! = nil
    var reverb: AKReverb! = nil
    var performance: AKPeriodicFunction! = nil

    public init() {
        pluckedString = AKPluckedString()

        delay = AKDelay(pluckedString) // <- objc_exception_throw here
        delay.time = 1.5 / Player.playRate
        delay.dryWetMix = 0.3
        delay.feedback = 0.2

        reverb = AKReverb(delay)

        performance = AKPeriodicFunction(frequency: Player.playRate) {
            var note = Player.scale.randomElement()
            let octave = [2, 3, 4, 5].randomElement() * 12
            if random(0, 10) < 1.0 { note += 1 }
            if !Player.scale.contains(note % 12) { print("ACCIDENT!") }

            let frequency = (note + octave).midiNoteToFrequency()
            if random(0, 6) > 1.0 {
                self.pluckedString.trigger(frequency: frequency)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that call to `AKDelay(pluckedString)` produces ObjC exception:

```
AKPluckedString.swift:init(frequency:amplitude:lowestFrequency:):94:Parameter Tree Failed
[avae] AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAudioEngine.mm:353:AttachNode: (node != nil)]
[General] required condition is false: node != nil
[General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff49d8d00b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff7096bc76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff49d92da2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff4610b75e _Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 158
    4   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff460ab1a2 _Z11_AVAE_CheckPKciS0_S0_b + 330
    5   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff4611f2e7 _ZN17AVAudioEngineImpl10AttachNodeEP11AVAudioNodeb + 63
    6   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff4611f267 -[AVAudioEngine attachNode:] + 67
    7   AudioKit                            0x000000010051de01 globalinit_33_0214DCBA62A4B4A95DF14CC0DE6A86C6_func60 + 13249
    8   AudioKit                            0x000000010051f24d globalinit_33_0214DCBA62A4B4A95DF14CC0DE6A86C6_func60 + 18445
    9   AudioKit                            0x0000000100512284 block_copy_helper.12 + 4852
    10  AudioKit                            0x0000000100519119 block_copy_helper.12 + 33161
    11  AudioKit                            0x0000000100639e8f block_copy_helper.12 + 38463
    12  AudioKit                            0x00000001006397ca block_copy_helper.12 + 36730
...
```

How can I fix this?

I am using AudioKit 4.0.4 / Swift 4.0.3 / XCode 9.2 (9C40b).

Comment: I ran your code without any crashes.  The error message you're getting looks like the error from not setting the Audiokit.output.  When are you calling AudioKit.start()? It will need to be after Audiokit.output = player.reverb (or whatever).

Comment: This is what makes it very weird.  Same code in playground works fine.  What I could figure out so far is that somehow a call to `AVAudioNode()` in AKPluckedString (well, in its superclass AKNode actually) returns a zero pointer.  No reason or error given by the CoreAudio though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it because your App Sandbox is on? My Xcode (9.2) is defaulting to App Sandbox on (Capabilities tab of project). This results in a AudioKit giving this error.

Comment: Yes!  That's was the reason (facepalm).